# JavaFX ScrollBar setOnMousePressed not working

Tags: java, javafx

really liking JavaFX but have come across this problem and wondered if it was a bug.

The ScrollBar.setOnMousePressed() doesn't seem to fire when it has been initialised with a handler. The code below demonstrates the problem:-

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Play extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static int cnt;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bug?");
        Button btn = new Button("This text will get replaced by the event handlers");

        ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar();

        // When pressing and releasing the ScrollBar thumb, we only get decrements
        // If you replace the ScrollBar with say a Button, then the code below works as you might expect.
        scrollBar.setOnMousePressed( event -> btn.setText("X" + cnt++));
        scrollBar.setOnMouseReleased( event -> btn.setText("X" + cnt--));

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(scrollBar);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 350, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Note, Im running on JDK 1.8.0_66 64 Bit on Microsoft Windows 10.

Comment: Probably the handlers that process mouse events on the scroll bar (in order to provide its usual functionality) consume mouse clicked events. If you use an event filter instead, it behaves as expected. What is your actual use case for something like this (i.e. why are you using fairly low-level event handling on a control like this)?

Comment: this is what I thought, but then why does this not happen on a Button? Also all the other events work as expected, including mouseClicked and mouseRelease. It seems inconsistent. The use case, is something I've done successfully in the past with Swing whereby I pop up a ToolTip which shows the location within a custom control whist the user drags the scroll bar thumb.

Comment: I will try the Event Filters like you suggest and get back to you.

Comment: Another approach might be to register the tooltip directly with the thumb. I haven't tried this, but you should be able to do it with a lookup: `Node thumb = scrollBar.lookup(".thumb");` `Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();` `Tooltip.install(thumb, tooltip);`. Then bind the text of the tooltip to the scroll bar's `value` property. This will be a slightly different UX (the tooltip pops up on hover, even without changing) but might work ok.

Comment: Like any UI toolkit, JavaFX does some things really well (e.g. observable properties and skinning with CSS) and some things less well. The ability to modify default behaviors of controls (i.e. change or add ways they react to user input) is definitely something the current version does not do well. We can hope this might improve in a later version: I know the skin classes become public API in JavaFX 9, which is a step forward, but not enough yet to make this kind of thing easier.

Comment: Your original suggestion of using the Event Filters solves my problem, and gives the exact appearance that I want. So thanks. Your later suggestion doesn't  really do this as well, I'd also argue that I'm not trying to modify the Scroll Bar component but just trying to capture some of its events - I can associate the ToolTip with any Node. I've raised the original problem as a potential bug with Oracle. I will post their conclusions here once I here from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround, as suggested by James_D, is to use EventFilters instead of setOnMousePressed(), as follows:-

So,

```
scrollBar.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
            event -> btn.setText("X" + cnt++));
```

instead of

```
scrollBar.setOnMousePressed( event -> btn.setText("X" + cnt++));
```

I believe .setOnMousePressed() should work, but doesn't because of a bug in the library. I've raised with oracle and will update the answer once oracle clarifies.